# Where do I place the ReCatptcha for firebase phone number login?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

The way I am interpreting the following code block:

```
window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
  'size': 'invisible',
  'callback': (response) => {
    // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
    onSignInSubmit();
  }
});
```

is that there should be an empty div with an id recaptchaVerifier and the new RecaptchaVerifier object should replace that div. How am I supposed to do this in react? I tried creating another component and returning the new RecaptchaVerifier to render on the mainpage but every time I try something like that it crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mentioned in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#use-invisible-recaptcha) but it's easy to miss.

> To use an invisible reCAPTCHA, create a `RecaptchaVerifier` object with the `size` parameter set to `invisible`, ***specifying the ID of the button that submits your sign-in form***. For example:

`sign-in-button` is the CSS ID of the submit button in your login form. To wire up the recaptcha, Add `sign-in-button` as the of your React components submit button. For example... `id="sign-in-button"`.

I found it easier to break up the login process into two separate steps. If your interested... Keep reading.

Below is an example implementation for Firebase Auth Phone Login. You'll see I'm breaking up the login into two methods. The first method is for your login form and the other is for signing in the user with the SMS Verification Code that was sent to their device.

```
const verifyPhoneNumber = async phone => {
  const appVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('login-button', { size: 'invisible' });
  const phoneNumber = normalizePhone(phone);

  return firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
    .then(response => response.verificationId);
};

const signInWithVerificationCode = (id, code) => {
  const phoneCredential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(id, code);

  return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(phoneCredential).then(login);
};
```